# Unable to split comma and quotes separated values

Tags: java

String is

```
"155350","7 1/4" Ginger Vase,- Case of 12","1001","41.4900","2016-10-31","2021-12-31","2016-11-01","A","N"
```

Its comma separated and enclosed in quotes. But it has quotes as Inch symbol as well.

Can you help me to build regexp to split this string array.

I tried `split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1)` but it considers Inch sign " as
field separator.
Above string has 9 values separated by quotes and comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimiter is a comma preceded and followed by quote:

```
split("(?<=\"),(?=\")",-1)
```

that is, look behind for double-quote, match a comma and look ahead for double-quote (both zero-width look ahead/behind to avoid *consuming* the quotes)

but not the best solution for parsing - may/will fail in some cases (comma and quotes as part of value).

Answer (score 2):

That's bad CSV, it cannot be successfully parsed because you cannot know if the embedded quote is data or a delimiter.

Normal CSV would double the quote, as in

```
"7 1/4"" Ginger Vase,- Case of 12"
```

The answer is that the input data is ambiguous and the data source must be corrected.  There is no solution at this stage.